# disable menu mark in ncurses menu

Tags: c, menu, ncurses

i'm trying to use ncurses for creating a boot menu.
i want to remove the selected item mark ( default to "-" ).

man set_menu_mark tells that i can change that string, but i cannot remove it.

any suggestion?
for avoiding your anti-poor-question filter i have to attach some code...

```
/* Set menu mark to the string " * " */
set_menu_mark(my_menu, "*");
/* this will reset the mark to default */
set_menu_mark(NULL,NULL);
/* i've tried this too */
set_menu_mark(my_menu.NULL);
```

Comment: Have you tried changing it to the empty string or a space?

Comment: NULL or empty => the cursor is a block of the background color.
space => the cursor is an underscore of the background color.
the space "workaround" it's the more nice...but not a solution....
thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
curs_set(0);
...
set_menu_mark(my_menu,NULL);
```

;)